# How to save video downloaded using Android default download manager in Android 10 in public directory?

Tags: java, android

Hi i am trying to download a video from server using API by default android download manager. everything is working fine but not in Android 10. i Want to save that video to my public directory that video should appear in photos and Files (working well <API 29)

code i am using

```
 private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    DownloadTask(Context context) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        PlayMovieActivity.mProgressDialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        PlayMovieActivity.mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        PlayMovieActivity.mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        PlayMovieActivity.mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);

        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //getPath();

        PlayMovieActivity.mProgressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (result != null) {
            savedownload();
            PlayMovieActivity.doneok.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            PlayMovieActivity.downprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            PlayMovieActivity.downbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            PlayMovieActivity.downnow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {

            PlayMovieActivity.downnow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            PlayMovieActivity.downbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            PlayMovieActivity.doneok.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            PlayMovieActivity.downprogress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            PlayMovieActivity.doneok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    openDown();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        PlayMovieActivity.input = null;
        PlayMovieActivity.connection = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            PlayMovieActivity.connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            PlayMovieActivity.connection.connect();
            if (PlayMovieActivity.connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + PlayMovieActivity.connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + PlayMovieActivity.connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            final int fileLength = PlayMovieActivity.connection.getContentLength();
            PlayMovieActivity.input = PlayMovieActivity.connection.getInputStream();


            callDownloadManager();


            int count;
            while ((count = PlayMovieActivity.input.read(data)) != -1) {

                total += count;
                if (fileLength > 0) {
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

                    final long finalTotal1 = total;
                    c.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            PlayMovieActivity.tv.setText(String.valueOf((int) (finalTotal1 * 100 / fileLength)));

                            PlayMovieActivity.downbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            PlayMovieActivity.downprogress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            PlayMovieActivity.doneok.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            PlayMovieActivity.downnow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            PlayMovieActivity.downnow.setText("Now Downloading : "+StoreClass.downtitle);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

CALL DOWNLOAD FUNCTION

```
 private void callDownloadManager() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(downurl);
    PlayMovieActivity.downloadManager = (DownloadManager) c.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    PlayMovieActivity.request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    PlayMovieActivity.request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    PlayMovieActivity.request.setDescription("Downloading");

    filename = downurl.substring(downurl.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {

        PlayMovieActivity.request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(c,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"Movie",filename);


    }
    else
    {
        PlayMovieActivity.request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Movie",filename);
    }

    PlayMovieActivity.request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);

    PlayMovieActivity.request.setMimeType(MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(downurl)));

    StoreClass.stop_Id = PlayMovieActivity.downloadManager.enqueue(PlayMovieActivity.request);
}
```

THIS CODE IS WORKING WELL <API29

```
 PlayMovieActivity.request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Movie",filename);
```

THIS CODE IS WORKING BUT VIDEO SAVED TO

```
android.data.com.package.files.storage.emulated.Folder
           
PlayMovieActivity.request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(c,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"Movie",filename);
```

MANIFEST

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

what i want to save or copy/move the whole video to photos gallery or public gallery

Comment: `PlayMovieActivity.request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Movie",filename)` The public dir is "Movies".

Comment: `PlayMovieActivity.input = PlayMovieActivity.connection.getInputStream();` If you are already that far i dont understand why you call the DownloadManager. A simple loop to read from stream and save to file stream was all you needed to do the job.

Comment: `PlayMovieActivity.input.read(data))` You download the whole file!? What are you doing with it? What are you doing with 'data' ? And you let the download manager download yet again. Why downloading a file twice?

Comment: `publishProgress((int)... ` That is the progress of your own downloading. Has nothing to do with the progress of the download manager. Please explain why you made this construction.

Comment: hi blackapps Thanks for your reply...1.)PlayMovieActivity.request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Movie",filename) This is working fine for API below 10 pls ignore this   2.)PlayMovieActivity.input = PlayMovieActivity.connection.getInputStream(); I am showing the UI percentage in my front end by this code its not downloading twice its just to show at front end 3.)PlayMovieActivity.input.read(data))  same as above its not downloading again just for UI update 4.) publishProgress((int)... yes i kw please ignore i just shared my whole code please edit the code if you want and correct it.

Comment: android.data.com.package.files.storage.emulated.Folder
           
PlayMovieActivity.request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(c,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"Movie",filename);
    THE MAIN PROBLEM IS THIS CODE IS NOT SAVING TO PUBLIC DIRECTORY LIKE GALLERY OR PHOTOS

Comment: Please look at my first comment. You should use a standard public directory.

Comment: `am showing the UI percentage in my front end by this code its not downloading twice its just to show at front end` You are downloading twice. And you show the download percentage of your own download. That percentage has nothing to do with the DownloadManager that is busy too.

Comment: okay i will remove the code but the main problem is i want to save the video to my public directory its working fine in API version <29 but not working in android 10  //ITS SAVING IN>>>>>>  android.data.com.package.files.storage.emulated.Folder
           
PlayMovieActivity.request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(c,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"Movie",filename);

Comment: My god... Movie? I told you already twice that it should be Movies.

Comment: It should be: `request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir("Movies", filename);` or `request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("Movies", filename);`

Comment: okay i did it and its now working Thankyou mate i was trying to figure it out whats going wrong that the code is not working in api>29 Thank you again my friend..

Comment: and 1 more thing how can i open the video file after downloading or how can i list them from this path>>>>>>request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir("Movies", filename)

Comment: Use ACTION_VIEW and a FileProvider to serve the file to an external app.